# VB.Net + Outlook 2013 language settings

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, outlook

I want to know the setting language Outlook (English, French or spanish...) is set by the user.
I'm writing a small asp.net (VB.Net) page that verify the language settings of the user before showing a page in the user language.
Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot interact with the user's machine from a web server.

Instead, use the `Accept-Language` header, which comes from the browser or OS.

Comment: The page will open in outlook as default opening page and will read and show the user's calendar.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: In Outlook, right click on the account Name (Left Panel, over Inbox), you will have access to Data File Properties... Select The Home Page Tab, it will let you set up the opening page of Outlook.